# How invoke a method in the method addTarget of the Button class when I create programmatically the button in a plain class in Swift

Tags: ios, oop, swift

I have a problem with the method "addTarget". In my program I read a file containing info on the Graphical Interface. According to this file, I programatically create the graphical elements.

I have a class for any possible type of element. For example, I have the Button class and a Text class. When I read and parse the file, I create an object of the appropriate class. If, for example, I read the tag "Button" I create a Button object, and set its properties (width, height, text, colour and gravity) and then I insert this object in a tree.

```
// ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    private let defaultPage : NSString = "http://xxx/index.xml"
    private var dataArray : NSArray = []     

    internal override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var parser : XMLParser = XMLParser.alloc().initWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(defaultPage)) as XMLParser
        parser.getViews().draw(self)
    }    

    func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        NSLog("Method1")
   }
}

// XMLParser
import Foundation
class XMLParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    private var views: Views?
    private var view: View?
    private var menu: Menu?
    private var menuItem: MenuItem?
    private var button: Button?
    private var parser = NSXMLParser()
    private var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    private var element = NSString()

    internal func initWithURL(url :NSURL) -> AnyObject {
        beginParsing(url)
        return self
    }    

    private func beginParsing(xmlUrl :NSURL) {
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: xmlUrl)
        parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
        parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
        parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }

    internal func getViews() -> View {
        return view!
    }

    internal func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!,didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName : String!, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary!) {
        element = elementName.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        switch(element as NSString){
        /*...*/
        case "button":
                button = Button(id:"", link:attributeDict.objectForKey("link") as NSString, width:attributeDict.objectForKey("width") as NSString, gravity:attributeDict.objectForKey("gravity") as NSString, text: "")
                view!.appendButton(button!)
                break
            default:
                break
        }

    }
}

// ButtonClass
class Button{
    private var id: String
    private var link: String
    private var width: String
    private var gravity: String
    private var text: String    

    internal init(id: String, link: String, width: String, gravity: String, text: String){
        self.id = id
        self.link = link
        self.width = width
        self.gravity = gravity
        self.text = text
    }

    internal func draw(uiViewController: UIViewController, position: Int){

        /*Different operations ...*/
        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x!, 130+50*CGFloat(position), CGFloat(width!), 40)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle(self.text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button.addTarget(uiViewController, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction2"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        uiViewController.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonAction2() {
        NSLog("h2")
    }

}
```

After I read the file, I print the tree in order. To print the tree, I call the method "draw" of my object. The method "draw" receives the UIViewController to print its different elements. Up to this point everything works all right.

The problem is when I click the button. I need to write the method in the principal UIViewController. My doubt is if there is any way to write this method in my Button class and then call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to solve my problem. I did that the "button" class inherit of "UIButton" class. This forced me to override the "init" method and others, but, to solve this other problem, I used a "convenience init". Thus, I can have a "constructor" without override the principal constructors of UIButton. In the other hand, I changed the code to create a button in the "draw" method. I put the new values in  attributes that my class inherit of the father instead of create a new button.

```
// ButtonClass
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Button: UIButton{

    private var idButton: String = ""
    private var link: String = ""
    private var width: String = ""
    private var gravity: String = ""
    private var text: String = ""

    convenience init(idButton: String, link: String, width: String, gravity: String, text: String){
        self.init()
        self.idButton = idButton
        self.link = link
        self.width = width
        self.gravity = gravity
        self.text = text
    }

    internal func draw(uiViewController: UIViewController, position: Int){
        /*Different operations ...*/
        self.frame = CGRectMake(x!, 130+50*CGFloat(position), CGFloat(width!), 40)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.setTitle(self.text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonActionTouchUpInside:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        uiViewController.view.addSubview(self)
    }

    internal func buttonActionTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton!) {
        NSLog("h2: "+self.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code in your Button class initializer:

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("yourMethod"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

`yourMethod` must be implemented in your Button class

Comment: If I pass "self" instead the UiViewController object that the method "draw" had received and I launch the App, I receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the AppDelegate class when I click in a button.