# Swift access control with target selectors

Tags: ios, swift, selector

Have a look at this example code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let letterButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        self.view.addSubview(letterButton)
        letterButton.addTarget(self, action:Selector("buttonDidTap:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    }

    func buttonDidTap(button: UIButton!) {
        print(button.char)
    }

}
```

The target action for the `UIButton` works fine as long as Selector is **public** or **internal**, but if it's **private**, it crashes due to *unrecognized selector sent to instance*

Is there any way I can achieve this ? I don't want to make tap function public or internal.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

you need `@objc` to expose a private method to objc runtime

```
@objc private func buttonDidTap(button:UIButton!) {
    println(button.char)
}
```

From [Xcode6 beta4 release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_4_o2p8fz/xcode_6_beta_4_release_notes.pdf)

> Declarations marked private are not exposed to the Objective-C runtime
>   if not otherwise annotated. IB outlets, IB actions, and Core Data
>   managed properties remain exposed to Objective-C whatever their access
>   level. If you need a private method or property to be callable from
>   Objective-C (such as for an older API that uses a selector-based
>   callback), add the @objc attribute to the declaration explicitly.! !

Comment: Great answer. And if you want to be able to mark your method as private in your Swift code and still be able to access it via selector, you can use private as well:

`@objc private func buttonDidTap(button:UIButton!) { ... }`

Comment: I am getting the same issue when I am trying to call the function from another swift class!? How can I call the function in one class from another class?

Comment: What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Also, why is this so?

Comment: @FamicTech what is the access level of the function you trying to call? Make sure it is not private or fileprivate and is not contained in private/fileprivate extension. And keep in mind that if another class is in different module, the function have to be with "public" or "open" access level.