# How to make a UIImageView tappable and cause it to do something? (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage, touch

(I just started using Swift a few days ago and am relatively new to programming, so please bear with me.) I am trying to make random blocks appear on the screen, and the user must tap them to make them disappear. I have been able to create the blocks, but I have no idea how to actually make them tappable. Can someone please help me? This is my code so far:

```
func createBlock(){

    let imageName = "block.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -50, width: size, height: size)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)



    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.xPosition, y: 590, width: self.size, height: self.size)

        }, completion: { animationFinished in


            imageView.removeFromSuperview()


    })



}
```

**Edit:** This is the new code I am trying:

```
func createBlock(){


    let imageName = "block.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -50, width: size, height: size)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped"))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tappedImageView = gestureRecognizer.view!
        tappedImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        score += 10
    }



    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.xPosition, y: 590, width: self.size, height: self.size)

        }, completion: { animationFinished in


            imageView.removeFromSuperview()


    })



}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Once you've create the view, you need to set it's userInteractionEnabled property to true.  Then you need to attach a gesture to it.

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
//now you need a tap gesture recognizer
//note that target and action point to what happens when the action is recognized.
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("imageTapped:"))
//Add the recognizer to your view.
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Now you still need the function, in this case imageTapped:, which is where the action happens when the gesture is recognized.  The gesture that was recognized will be sent as an argument, and you can find out which imageView was tapped from they gestures view property.

```
func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //tappedImageView will be the image view that was tapped.
    //dismiss it, animate it off screen, whatever.
    let tappedImageView = gestureRecognizer.view!
}
```

Comment: @JeremyPope this is kind of embarrassing, but I still can't figure it out! So I added the code that you suggested and in the function "imageTapped" I just remove the "tappedimageview" from superview. When I actually run the program, nothing happens when I tap the blocks ):

Comment: can you put a breakpoint or a print on in the function to make sure it is being called?  How are you removing the tapped image from the super view?

Comment: @JeremyPope I posted the new code so you can see what I added in the function. I don't think it works though; when something is pressed, it's supposed to increased the score by 10, and I have a NSTimer that runs a function that updates the score every second so the player can see the score.

Comment: Two thins.   Target: self is referring to the class (probably your ViewController class), so it is looking for a method inside the class.  It looks like you have the method inside the createBlock method.  Move it outside to the class itself.

Comment: In addition, it appears that since the view is animating, the gesture recognizer is looking for taps either where it starts, or where it finishes.  The solution is going to be a touch trickier.  I'll update my answer shortly, have to run it through Xcode to verify.

Answer (score 7):

In swift 3.0:

```
        imvEditName.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
        imvEditName.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

And the target method:

```
func imageTapped(sender: UIImageView) {
    print("image tapped")
}
```

Comment: And in swift 4.x, the imageTapped function needs `@objc` declared before it.

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer is still accurate for adding a tap recognizer to a UIImageView, however it is not sufficient for the purposes of a view that is animating.  If you are actually creating a game, you'll likely want to look into SpriteKit, as it is literally tailor made for this.  However, this can be accomplished with normal UIKit.  I've tested two approaches, which both work.

*Both approaches worked far better on an actual device than in the simulator*

**Approach 1, Simpler yet slightly less precise** *up to a tenth of second slower in my tests.*

Instead of adding a tap gesture to the UIImageView, add the gesture to the superview.  Keep a reference to your blocks in an array property, and check if any blocks are intercepted by the tap.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let size = CGFloat(40)
    let xPosition = CGFloat(14)
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse
    var blocks = [UIImageView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Adding recognizer to the whole view.
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("screenTapped:"))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        blocks.append(createBlock())
    }

    //changed to return the created block so it can be stored in an array.
    func createBlock() -> UIImageView {
        let imageName = "block.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -40, width: size, height: size)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.xPosition, y: 590, width: self.size, height: self.size)
            }, completion: { animationFinished in
                imageView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.blocks.append(self.createBlock())
        })
        return imageView
    }

    func screenTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(view)
        //This is to keep track of the blocks to remove from the array.
        //If you remove them as you iterate the array, and you have more than 
        //one block to remove, you may end up removing the wrong block
        //or with an index out of bounds.
        var removeBlocks = [Int]()
        for (index, block) in enumerate(blocks) {
            //this is the frame of the view as we see it on screen.
            //unfortunately block.frame is not where we see it making a recognizer
            //on the block itself not work.
            if block.layer.presentationLayer().frame.contains(tapLocation) {
                //Then this block was clicked.
                block.removeFromSuperview()
                removeBlocks.append(index)
            }
        }
        //get the indexes ro remove backwards so we are removing from
        //back to front.
        for index in removeBlocks.reverse() {
            blocks.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }

}
```

**Approach 2, Best Performance** *outside of SpriteKit*

In approach two, you subclass UIView, and set your main view to it instead of the UIView.  You only need to override a single method.  I'm storing the block array in the view for convenience.

First the TouchView.

```
import UIKit

class TouchView: UIView {
    var blocks = [UIImageView]()
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // ignoring multiple touches for now
        if touches.count == 1 {
            if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
                let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self)
                //This is to keep track of the blocks to remove from the array.
                //If you remove them as you iterate the array, and you have more than
                //one block to remove, you may end up removing the wrong block
                //or with an index out of bounds.
                var removeBlocks = [Int]()
                for (index, block) in enumerate(blocks) {
                    //this is the frame of the view as we see it on screen.
                    //unfortunately block.frame is not where we see it making a recognizer
                    //on the block itself not work.
                    if block.layer.presentationLayer().frame.contains(touchLocation) {
                        //Then this block was clicked.
                        block.removeFromSuperview()
                        removeBlocks.append(index)
                    }
                }
                //get the indexes ro remove backwards so we are removing from
                //back to front.
                for index in removeBlocks.reverse() {
                    blocks.removeAtIndex(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the ViewController would look like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let size = CGFloat(40)
    let xPosition = CGFloat(14)
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse
    var blocks = [UIImageView]()
    // computed get only property for conveniece of accessing block array
    var touchView:TouchView {
        get {
            return self.view as! TouchView
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        touchView.blocks.append(createBlock())
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func createBlock() -> UIImageView {
        let imageName = "block.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -40, width: size, height: size)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.xPosition, y: 590, width: self.size, height: self.size)
            }, completion: { animationFinished in
                imageView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.touchView.blocks.append(self.createBlock())
        })
        return imageView
    }
}
```

In my tests, this seems to work pretty good, even with quickly animated "blocks".  Again, if you are planning on making a full fledged game, you should really look at SpriteKit.  There is a really simple tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners) that should get you started.  If you can remove the accepted answer from my previous answer, that would help others not be lead down the wrong path, unless they only are looking to add a gesture to a non-moving UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

By Default, image view user interaction is not enabled, so be sure to enable it by setting it to true.

```
let myImageView = UIImageView()
myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using a `UIImageView`, you could try use a Custome `UIButton` and replace the default button image with yours. Hence, you do not need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each UIImageView. @JeremyPope 's approach is actually more efficient compare to this approach.

Handling [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html) is pretty simple, its subclass of `UIControl` so there are properties like `hide` and `enabled` and you can manipulate them in the way you want.

What you need to do is to create `UIButton` programmaticly, just like you they way you creating `UIImageView`. The way to create them is similar to `UIImageView`, read more on [create UIButton programmaticly in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102191/make-a-uibutton-programatically-in-swift).

The image below is how a custom `UIButton` looks like.

[image]

Leave comments if you need more info.

Comment: This seems like a heavy handed approach.  The button still has a UIImageView inside of it, along with a lot of other things the questioner doesn't need for his current implementation.  If he is creating countless numbers of them, why make the objects even heavier than they need to be?

Comment: @JeremyPope Yes, you are right. This is my approach to solve this problem. Your approach is definitely more efficient than mine.