# Can I programmatically create WKInterfaceButton?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

just a quick question if this is possible at all: can I create `WKInterfaceButton` elements for the AppleWatch programmatically? Or do I have to layout everything in InterfaceBuilder and cannot dynamically add UI elements on the watch?

So far I haven't found anything like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102191/make-a-uibutton-programatically-in-swift) for the AppleWatch with watchOS 2 and I am unclear about the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/).

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create `WKInterfaceObjects` programmatically and add them to the view hierarchy. The only exception being `WKInterfaceControllers` that you can push / present programmatically (although you still have to add them to the storyboard first)

Comment: OK thanks, that's a downer. I wanted to represent a list of buttons in the UI that I get from the iPhone's App and that can be configured there. As a workaround I will now use a `WKInterfacePicker` and then see which item was selected to segue to the next view.

Comment: Can't you use an `WKInterfaceTable` for that?

Comment: Wow, yes, I didn't know about `WKInterfaceTable` yet. Thanks!