# How can I call an action through UIButton variable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in a prototype `UItableviewcell` that is made in a nib.
The UITableView is inside a UIViewController.
The requirement is: When I press the `UIButton`, a segue should be performed from `Main UIViewController` to another second `UIViewController` . I can access the UIButton IBOutlet from the table , so is there any way to call a function through that UIButton Variable.  
`// for reference
 let x= cell.followButton;`

Comment: Have you check the docs for UIButton? What you are looking for is shown in there.

Comment: There are plenty of answer for this question in stackOverFlow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24102191/2695909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a target to the button to call a method in your view controller. In this code, `self` is your view controller.

```
cell.followButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then implement `buttonPressed` to handle segueing.

```
func buttonPressed() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: self)
}
```