# How to reference Swift Playground itself?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

from [How to create a button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-create-button-programmatically-in-swift)

self doesn't work in swift playground :

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

error :

> Playground execution failed: error: :42:13: error: use of
>   unresolved identifier 'self'

I also tried to create a class with buttonAction method inside it compiles but when I click on the button nothing prints in console

```
import UIKit

class myself {


    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        println("Button tapped")
    }

}

var s = myself()

// Create View
var f = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height:200)
var view = UIView(frame:f)


// Create Button
var b = UIButton(frame: f)
b.setTitle("Hello", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
b.addTarget(s, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

view.addSubview(b)

view
```

Comment: Is that your full code? You can't reference `self` outside of some sort of a class method

Comment: @BergQuester yes I know for self that's why I ask for alternative :  how do I reference the playground where I would define buttonAction func ? I also tried to create a class myself but when I click button it doesn't print anything (see code update)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because right now swift playground can't simulate inputs. In this case touch events

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, the playgrounds aren't actually interactive. Yes, you can scrub back and forth in time in some cases, but you can't actually interact with the controls.

Comment: @BergQuester what a pity I'm crying :(

Comment: I know! Join with me by filing a bug report for a feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Never use bugreport. When I go there I got empty list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, controls in playgrounds are not interactive.

I tried getting around the non-interactivity of playground controls the other day by creating and displaying an `NSWindow` for a Mac playground, however, the result was that the window simply flashed behind the playground.

Best that I can tell after some probing into `NSProcess`, `NSBundle`, `NSApplication` and watching the system Activity Monitor, the playground actually compiles your code, loads it into a stub app, executes, the playground captures the results and displays them then the stub app exits or waits around for the next execution. This means by the time you see the results, the code is no longer executing.

If you're curious, you can try the code below in a playground to see what I mean. If you open Activity Monitor and filter on `PlaygroundStub_OSX` you can see the process that runs the code launch. It is oftentimes in a "Not responding" state. I've also included a screen capture of the results of the probing portion of the code.

```
import Cocoa

var app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
app.hidden

var procInfo = NSProcessInfo.processInfo()
procInfo.processName
procInfo.arguments

var bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
bundle.bundlePath



var window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 400, height: 400), styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask, backing: .Buffered, defer: false)


var view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))

var textField = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 100, height: 20))

textField.stringValue = "Test"

view.addSubview(textField)

var button = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 30, y: 60, width: 100, height: 30))

button.highlight(true)

var buttonCell:NSButtonCell = button.cell() as NSButtonCell
buttonCell.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle


view.addSubview(button)

window.contentView.addSubview(view)



window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I was able to get a semi-functional OS X window in a Swift playground and placed the code in a [github repo](https://github.com/BergQuester/Interactive-Window-Swift-Playground). I'm not sure if an interactive UIKit based view is possible yet.

Answer (score 8):

With Xcode 7.3 this is now supported. You'll need to declare an ObjectiveC object or expose a function using `@objc` keyword as a target:

```
class Responder : NSObject {
    func action() {
        print("Button pressed!")
    }
}

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 667.0))
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = containerView
let responder = Responder()

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
button.setTitle("TEST", forState: .Normal)
button.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(Responder.action), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
containerView.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: This works! However, there's 2 things that you should add to the description. 1) import XCPlayground 2) display the element in the assistant editor.

Comment: how to call containerView variable inside the action() method

Answer (score 1):

I do this successfully with Cocoa.

Make your class a subclass of NSObject. Create an NSWindow in your class and move the button and the action into your class. Then you can set the button's target to self.

Try it with UIKit and let us know if it works.