# How to add a UIButton to Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

So I opened up playground, I just want to add a simple UIButton (or a simple UIView) for testing purposes. I can't get it to display though. This is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit

var uiButton    = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
uiButton.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
uiButton.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
//self.view.addSubview(uiButton) <-- doesn't work
```

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is now possible with Xcode 7.3, see answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36228746/1019088

Answer (score 4):

I think you can add button into playground and your code is correct you can see your button here when you click on Quick Look:

[image]

or you can see that button with clicking on Value History:

[image]

you dont need to add that into view.

Answer (score 2):

If you `import XCPlayground` in your playground you can show views using:

```
let view=UIView()
//other setup
XCPShowView("View Title",view)
```

This will show the view in the assistant editor

To show the assistant editor goto `View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor`

Comment: This was deprecated in Xcode 7.1; new approach is `let view = UIView` `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view`.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/XCPlaygroundModuleRef/XCPlayground.html for further details.

Answer (score 0):

`import XCPlayground` has been deprecated and is now `import PlaygroundSupport`.
You need to create your view first and give it a size.

`let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black`

then add `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view` to be able to see the view in the assistant editor.

now that you have created your view, and you can see the live preview of it.  You can now add other views to it.  In my playground I added several views so I created simple function with a default width and height.

`func addSquareView(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int = 100, height: Int = 100, color: UIColor) {
    let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
    newView.backgroundColor = color
    view.addSubview(newView)
}`

`addSquareView(x: 100, y: 100, color: .blue)`

Now there is a blue square in the center of my view.

Answer (score 0):

```
I was just doing my sorting programming and pated the code..it will help you to add a button in playgroud with target.

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let aButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
aButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
aButton.setTitle("Run Sorting", for: .normal)
aButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
aButton.clipsToBounds = true

class Sorting {
    
    @objc func callSorting() {
        self.getSortedArrayUsingSelectionSort()
    }
    
    func getSortedArrayUsingSelectionSort() {
        
        var arr = [4, 9, 10, 6, 1, 3]
        let n = arr.count
        
        for i in 0..<(n - 1) {
            var minIndex = i
            for j in (i+1)..<n {
                if arr[j] < arr[minIndex] {
                    minIndex = j
                }
            }
            if minIndex != i {
                let temp = arr[minIndex]
                arr[minIndex] = arr[i]
                arr[i] = temp
            }        }
        print(arr)
    }
  }

let target = Sorting()

aButton.addTarget(target, action: #selector(Sorting.callSorting), for: .touchUpInside)
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView

containerView.addSubview(aButton)
```