# UIButtonType not displaying in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift-playground

I'm messing around in a Swift playground, trying to demonstrate different types of UIButtons built into the Cocoa library. And I'm curious why this works:

[image: Creating a button that works]

and yet this doesn't:

[image]

The only thing I'm doing differently should be constructing them. The first one, I'm constructing using UIButton's constructor; the second one, I'm creating using a UIButton static method that returns anyObject that should be a button of the given type. So, in effect, they should be the same, right? Why does the first one display for me, yet the second one doesn't?

Comment: Check this question and answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27637398/3202193

Answer (score 0):

You can see that button into `Assistant Editor` like this:

First add `import XCPlayground` at the top of your playGround then add this code:

```
var myButton1 = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)
myButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
myButton1.setTitle("This is a button", forState: .Normal)
XCPShowView("View Title",myButton1)
```

To show the assistant editor goto `View` > `Assistant Editor` > `Show Assistant Editor`

And you can see your button like this:

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: This does fix my problem, thanks! However, I'm still kind of confused as to why it won't show in the quick view as above - is it being interpreted differently by the system?

Comment: I think compiler is taking this differently. thats why it is not showing you like  other button code.