# How to use `SELF` in swift playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, observers

How to reference Swift Playground itself?

I am trying to use `NSNotificationCenter` to observe some variable, but i do not know how to implement it on `Playground`.

Here is my code. I just want to observe the `timeout` variable, but without the `willSet` method.

```
var timeout = false
var cont: Int8 = 1

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: timeout, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: &cont)
```

Is there any way to do it on playground?

Comment: You can not only add self there, but any instance of object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference Swift Playground itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108093/how-to-reference-swift-playground-itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is KVO playground on gitHub, try this one https://github.com/rectalogic/KVOPlayground

or you might interested in this one:
[How to reference Swift Playground itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108093/how-to-reference-swift-playground-itself)