# Swift Playgrounds - use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Tags: swift, swift3

I am using Swift playgrounds trying to make an interactive app in which the user can click on a button to perform an action.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))

func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
print("Please Help!")
}
```

It is giving me the error:

> 'use of unresolved identifier self'

.
How can I fix this in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

That code isn't going to work unless it's inside a class that inherits from `NSObject`.

If it is in a class and you're still getting that error, it's probably because `tapGesture` is a property. Properties generally can't use `self` during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Put @objc before func tapBlurButton...

Answer (score -1):

Put those code in class.

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {
    [your code with self]
}
```

Because there's nothing to say `self` and playground.

And [How to reference Swift Playground itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108093/how-to-reference-swift-playground-itself)