# UIButton touch not registering (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, target

I've created a button, but for some reason, the touch isn't recognizing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var settingsButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        settingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 50, 35, 35, 35)
        settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings-button"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("settingsButtonPressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(settingsButton)
}

func settingsButtonPressed(){
        println("Settings selected")
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, it's just not registering when I touch the button. I've tried making a button of type UIButtonType.Custom as well, and I've tried the selector as

```
Selector("settingsButtonPressed")
Selector("settingsButtonPressed:") //I changed the function to settingsButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)
"settingsButtonPressed"
"settingsButtonPressed:" //I changed the function to settingsButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)
```

Comment: its working here .. 
are you sharing everything which override or been added to your view...
which version of Xcode you are using ! ...

Comment: Hmmm. I'm using version 6.0.1. I'm not sure what you mean by "are you sharing everything which override or been added to your view"

Comment: is there any thing else is been add to your view other than `settingsButton` .? . are you sharing the complete code ..

Comment: Yes, I have added other views, but I've gone into view debugger and seen that this view is on top. Was that what you were thinking?

Comment: it just i tested the same code .. and its working . :/ ..

Comment: Yeah, it must be something like that. At least I know the code is fine though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create button programmatically in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-create-button-programmatically-in-swift)

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to pick up a problem when a subview/button is not clickable, I will mention the possible ways to fix it below.

1. You should make sure isUserInteractionEnabled = true
2. Make sure isEnabled = true
3. You can use the Xcode 3d view hierarchy tool. You do this on Xcode by first running your app, and navigating to the screen where touches don't work. Click on the button highlighted in blue as per my example below.

[image: XcodeGraphicalTool]

After you do the above, your app will be paused and a graphical hierarchy of your app will appear, when it does zoom in and rotate to see what View is blocking your button/View. check image below for reference

[image]

4. Lastly a subview might not be clickable because its outside the bounds of its super view so you need to make sure all subviews are in your superview bounds.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

One common cause of this problem that I don't see mentioned here is that the button's userInteractionEnabled value must be true.

A much more unique cause is when the parent view is the problem. In my case I had an image view within a container view, and added a button as a subview of the image view so it would display on top and allow users to tap the button to change the image.

Nothing I did would get the button action to work, until I tried making the button a subview of the container view, and it suddenly started working. In my case it appears the UIImageView wasn't allowing subviews to get the tap events.

Comment: Yes, adding a button as a subview to an image view was my problem too. Adding it as a subview of a UIView instead did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are a link is broken between the UI element and the view controller.
Try recreating the link between the ui element and the view controller.

On your view controller look over to the right hand bar where you set breakpoints and look for a little circle on the line where your button is linked. If it's filled you're linked.
If the middle is hollow it's not linked.

Comment: I never created a UIButton through the interface builder. I built it programatically. No circle, hollowed or filled.

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
self.settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("settingsButtonPressed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and

```
func settingsButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!){
        println("Settings selected")
}
```

Look at the answer from [How to create a button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-create-button-programmatically-in-swift)

provided by Anil . It works I checked.