# Set Action Listener Programmatically in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I saw some example codes that assign the same OnClick event to all the buttons  in Android  (even if they perform completely different action) . How can do it with Swift

Android Example:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
} 

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override 
     public void onClick(View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.button1:
                  //DO something 
             break; 
             case R.id.button2:
                  //DO something 
             break; 
             case R.id.button3:
                  //DO something 
             break; 
         } 

   } 
};
```

Note: I don't want create the button programatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create button programmatically in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-create-button-programmatically-in-swift)

Comment: No... i need add the same listener to multiple buttons... this is not duplicate.

Comment: call the addTarget method on each button pointing to the same action?

Comment: UIcontrol has a method -addTarget which can be pointed to the same "listener" [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:). But judging from your code why not have 4 listeners instead of one which determines which one of the buttons was pressed?

Comment: @cream-corn Because you may have a dynamic table structure with buttons that can be mapped using row index.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

On iOS, you're not setting a listener; you add a target (an object) and an action (method signature, "selector" in iOS parlance) to your `UIControl` (which `UIButton` is a subclass of):

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", for: .touchUpInside)
button2.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", for: .touchUpInside)
button3.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", for: .touchUpInside)
```

The first parameter is the target object, in this case `self`. The action is a selector (method signature) and there are basically two options (more on that later). The [control event](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events) is a bit specific to the `UIControl` - `.TouchUpInside` is commonly used for tapping a button.

Now, the action. That's a method (the name is your choice) of one of the following formats:

```
func buttonClicked()
func buttonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject?)
```

To use the first one use "buttonClicked", for the second one (which you want here) use "buttonClicked:" (with trailing colon). The `sender` will be the source of the event, in other words, your button.

```
func buttonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
  if sender === button1 {
    // do something
  } else if sender === button2 {
    // do something
  } else if sender === button3 {
    // do something
  }
}
```

(this assumes that `button1`, `button2` and `button3` are instance variables).

Instead of this one method with the big switch statement consider using separate methods for each button. Based on your specific use case either approach might be better:

```
func button1Clicked() {
  // do something
}

func button2Clicked() {
  // do something
}

func button3Clicked() {
  // do something
}
```

Here, I'm not even using the `sender` argument because I don't need it.

P.S.: Instead of adding targets and actions programmatically you can do so in your Storyboard or nib file. In order to expose the actions you put `IBAction` in front of your function, e.g.:

```
@IBAction func button1Clicked() {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 76):

**Swift 4.***

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And the button triggers this function:

```
@objc func didButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: should now be written as #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)) or use #selector(buttonClicked(_:))

btnAll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
then change your function like,

 func buttonClicked(_ sender : UIButton){

 ....
 }

Comment: how do I check which button was clicked if I set the same function for all buttons?

Comment: To check which button was clicked you set a different tag when creating them. _button.tag = 1_ (or 2 or 3). Then you use: _switch sender.tag {case 1:..._

Answer (score 3):

**An Swift 5 Extension Solution**

Create A SwiftFile "*SetOnClickListener.swift*" 
**copy paste this code**

```
import UIKit

class ClosureSleeve {
  let closure: () -> ()

  init(attachTo: AnyObject, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
    self.closure = closure
    objc_setAssociatedObject(attachTo, "[\(arc4random())]", self, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
  }

  @objc func invoke() {
    closure()
  }
}

extension UIControl {
    func setOnClickListener(for controlEvents: UIControl.Event = .primaryActionTriggered, action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let sleeve = ClosureSleeve(attachTo: self, closure: action)
        addTarget(sleeve, action: #selector(ClosureSleeve.invoke), for: controlEvents)
    }
}
```

**How To use**
for example buttonA is a UIButton

```
buttonA.setOnClickListener {
  print("button A clicked")                  
}
```

Comment: how to get the target element such as in  "sender" in @objc func didButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // your code goes here
}
?