# UIView touch event in controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

How can I add UIView touchbegin action or touchend action programmatically as Xcode is not providing from Main.storyboard?

Comment: That one is for button, the OP wants to add event for UIView

Comment: Use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with the `minimumPressDuration` set to zero. [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38143429/3681880) It doesn't require subclassing or overriding anything.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You will have to add it through code. First, create the view and add it to the hierarchy:

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

After that initialize gesture recognizer. Until Swift 2:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "someAction:")
```

After Swift 2:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.someAction (_:)))
```

Then bind it to the view:

```
self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Swift 3:

```
func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){     
  // do other task
}
```

Swift 4 just add `@objc` before `func`:

```
@objc func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){     
    // do other task
}
```

Swift UI:

```
Text("Tap me!").tapAction {
    print("Tapped!")
}
```

Comment: I have did that it is giving me an error when i click on the uiView. My code:       
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.uiPendingView, action: "touchPending")
        self.uiPendingView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
and method:    
   func touchPending(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("METHOD>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    }

Comment: just add : in "touchPending:" ans in function it look like func touchPending(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)

Comment: you are missing ':' in action.

Comment: Hi, How can I distinguish which UIView got clicked when they all have the same someAction function?

Comment: Easiest way would be to use tag property and then in function determine which view is sender

Comment: Furthermore you can design a custom view xib and then bind it into the touch event. But it depends on your requirement. [Here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371194/set-action-listener-programmatically-in-swift)

Answer (score 103):

**Swift 4 / 5:**

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.checkAction))
self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

@objc func checkAction(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.checkAction(sender:)))
self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func checkAction(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

Comment: FIRST 2 LINES SHOULD BE CALLED FROM VIEWDIDLOAD!

Answer (score 26):

Updating @Crashalot's answer for Swift 3.x:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Updating @Chackle's answer for Swift 2.x:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Put this in your `UIView` subclass (it's easiest if you make a sublcass for this functionality).

```
class YourView: UIView {

  //Define your initialisers here

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
      let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
      // do something with your currentPoint
    }
  }

  override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
      let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
      // do something with your currentPoint
    }
  }

  override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
      let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
      // do something with your currentPoint
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Chacle, I have more than 10 Uiview in my page, and i want to add action in some of Sub UIView. So for that what should i change?

Comment: It depends what you want to use it for. Do you want to tell which `UIView` you press or do you want to handle some presses in each of the `UIView`?

Comment: I want touchevent for some specifi UIview only.

Answer (score 9):

For swift 4

```
@IBOutlet weak var someView: UIView!  
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.someAction (_:)))
self.someView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

@objc func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("view was clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Create outlets from views that were created in StoryBoard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var orangeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var greenView: UIView!
```

Override the touchesBegan method. There are 2 options, everyone can determine which one is better for him.

1. Detect touch in special view.

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
           if touch.view == self.redView {
               tapOnredViewTapped()
           } else if touch.view == self.orangeView {
               orangeViewTapped()
           } else if touch.view == self.greenView {
               greenViewTapped()
           } else {
               return
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. Detect touch point on special view.

   ```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       if let touch = touches.first {
           let location = touch.location(in: view)
           if redView.frame.contains(location) {
               redViewTapped()
           } else if orangeView.frame.contains(location) {
               orangeViewTapped()
           } else if greenView.frame.contains(location) {
               greenViewTapped()
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Lastly, you need to declare the functions that will be called, depending on which view the user clicked.

```
func redViewTapped() {
    print("redViewTapped")
}

func orangeViewTapped() {
    print("orangeViewTapped")
}

func greenViewTapped() {
    print("greenViewTapped")
}
```

Comment: Very well great example thanks to showing me!! that we can also do this using touchEvent .. i know only two way button and gesture.. Thanks +1

Comment: by the way, this touch will not work in simulator. so if you're working on simulator, you can't test the code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this way;
create an extension.

```
extension UIView {
    
    func addTapGesture(action : @escaping ()->Void ){
        let tap = MyTapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        tap.action = action
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    }
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: MyTapGestureRecognizer) {
        sender.action!()
    }
}

class MyTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var action : (()->Void)? = nil
}
```

and use this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!
testView.addTapGesture{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4.2:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewLabel1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewLabel2: UIView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(someAction(_:)))
    self.viewLabel1.addGestureRecognizer(myView)
}

 @objc func someAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
   viewLabel2.isHidden = true
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just an update to above answers :**

If you want to have see changes in the click event, i.e. Color of your UIVIew shud change whenever user clicks the UIView then make changes as below...

```
class ClickableUIView: UIView {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
                // do something with your currentPoint
            }

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()//Color when UIView is clicked.
        }

        override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
                // do something with your currentPoint
            }

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()//Color when UIView is clicked.
        }

        override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
                // do something with your currentPoint
            }

            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()//Color when UIView is not clicked.

}//class closes here
```

Also, call this Class from Storyboard & ViewController as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var panVerificationUIView:ClickableUIView!
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating @stevo.mit's answer for Swift 4.x:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        // do something with your currentPoint
    }
}
```