# Swift tap gesture recognizer not triggering

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to trigger the tap gesture whenever I tap on an item in my UIPickerView.

I'm using the following code for LongPress Gesture which works fine. However if I switch to UITapGestureRecognizer, nothing is triggered.

```
@IBOutlet weak var showClaims: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showClaims.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ClaimVC.SelectClaimInfo))
      
    showClaims.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
}

func SelectClaimInfo() {
    GetClaimInfo()
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you added a tap gesture recognizer to showClaims.

Comment: Is .userInteractionEnabled true on the UIPickerView

Comment: @dfd I have replaced the tap with a longPress. Same code is used for tap as the one for long press.

Comment: @Emptyless yes it is enabled

Comment: You should set delegate to gesture recognizer so `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` will be called

Comment: I thought so - you probably should show the *full* code that *isn't* working instead of what works.

Comment: @dfd code edited.

Comment: By asking for full code I wanted to see a bit more - where the "let" (shouldn't be called Tap but tap instead BTW) and the add reside, along with other things the may conflict. More to the point - why are you using delegates and `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`? When I use three simultaneous gesture (tap, pan, rotate) things work without this. (I believe if I added a fourth - long press - this would be true too.) I'm hoping the full code would help me to answer the issue.

Comment: @dfd I was trying something with long press and tap, then added the simultaneous gesture function but turns out it has no use. Ill update the full code now

Comment: I'd think @Darkwonder is right, but there's a key difference going on. That code adds the gesture to the view while your code adds it to the UIPickerView. If that's the issue (I'm not sure) you *could* wire up the tap to the superview and use a *hitTest()* on the UIPickerView's layer.

Comment: @dfd I've tried the same code on a label field and it works. Probably it is something with the picker view that is missing

Comment: I'm not sure what your need is, but if it's the picker view maybe you could do a hitTest() on it's layer?

Answer (score 1):

For who Tap Gesture not work for them until make everything as that:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

try to conforms `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and then
mKE `tap.delegate = self` and you must implement this  `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method
make

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @dfd is correct in the comments.

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTapGesture()
}

private func setupTapGesture()
{
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                            action: #selector(myVC.doStuff(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func doStuff(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {}
```

You did miss the:

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Update: check touchesBegan from this SO: [touchesBegan Swift 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505165/swift-uiview-touch-event-in-controller)
With it you can check if your UIPicker is reaciving touchers properly.