# swift @IBAction from tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift4, ibaction, iboutlet

I need to trigger a function by clicking on a tableViewCell,
until now I used @IBAction, but that option is only available with button type (I haven't found another way..)
this is the way I now of:

```
@IBAction func springPrs(_ sender: Any) {
    //doing stuff.. 
}
```

but now I have an `@IBOutlet`

```
@IBOutlet weak var nextTrackCell: nextTableViewCell!
```

and I want to trigger a function by clicking on it. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong approach, you should implement a delegate method from `UITableViewDelegate` called `didSelectRowAt`:

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          //do your stuff here.
        }
```

Comment: thanks, but the thing is I created a singe cell outside of a table view, I'm new in swift, I'm guessing it's not the right thing to do(i'd like to know the disadvantages in this), but still, is there a way?

Comment: Is, this is the right way to do what you want. Also, you should not create a cell outside a tableview. cells are made for use with a tableview, not alone. If you are using a single cell, consider switching it by a UIView instead

Comment: and how can I create an "onclick" function for UIview?

Comment: this answer will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505165/swift-uiview-touch-event-in-controller

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add an action directly to a table view cell because it violates the MVC design pattern and there is a handy callback already built into `UITableViewDelegate` to make this really easy.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // do something when the top row tapped
    } else {
        // do something when any other row is tapped
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the override keyword will trigger a compiler error.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra you're right, my apologies. That would be the code if using a `UITableViewController` where the delegate callbacks are already implemented.

Comment: Yeah, I use this approach as well hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a closure inside the cell, this is what I tend to use when having to pass some action to the view controller.

```
var onButtonPressed: (() -> ())?

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    onButtonPressed?()
}
```

And use it like so in `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.onButtonPressed = { [unowned self] in
    // Do what you need to, no need to capture self however, if you won't access it.
}
```