# How to trigger an event when a user touches specific part of the screen - ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom pop up which I have made using a UIViewController (presentation: 'over current context') -  please see below.  What I would like to do is dismiss the UIViewController once the user touches the top - dark half- of the screen, which does not contain the menu options.  What event can i trigger to get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Use a tap gesture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift, UIView touch event in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505165/swift-uiview-touch-event-in-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tap gesture to the darkView and inside it do

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
mydarkView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

//

```
// 3. this method is called when a tap is recognized
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:true)
}
```

**OR** use

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, 
         with event: UIEvent?)
```