# Don't Click button inside in TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have added one Button into `tableview` button is not clicked. The button is not clicked on the top of `TableView`. What should I do to make the button clickable? I need to make the CircleMenu button clickable. The button is now on top of tableView3. Do I need to add the button to the `tableView`?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = CircleMenu(
                        frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width/2 - 10, y: view.frame.height - 270, width: 50, height: 50),
                        normalIcon:"icon_menu",
                        selectedIcon:"icon_close",
                        buttonsCount: 3,
                        duration: 4,
                        distance: 85)
                    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatSkyBlue
                    button.delegate = self
                    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2.0
                  view.addSubview(button)

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if tableView == self.tableView1 {

        if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {
            let cell:DeviceTableViewCell2 = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2


            let deviceItem: Device3New = itemsNew[indexPath.row]

            let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tittleNewTapped(_:)))
            let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tittleNewTapped2(_:)))



                return cell
            }
        }

        if tableView == self.tableView2 {
            if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
                let cell:DeviceTableViewCell2 = tableView2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

                let deviceItem: Device3 = items[indexPath.row]



cell.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.leftToRight, frame: self.view.frame, colors: [UIColor.flatPowderBlueDark, UIColor.flatSand])
                return cell

            }

        }
        if tableView == self.tableView3 {
            if !chipnumber3.text!.isEmpty {
                let cell:DeviceTableViewCell2 = tableView3.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew2, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2


                cell.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.leftToRight, frame: self.view.frame, colors: [UIColor.flatPowderBlueDark, UIColor.flatSand])
                return cell

            }

        }

        return UITableViewCell()

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the delegate methods [Delegate Methods](https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu#delegate-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a target to the button:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And then a selector method:

```
@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("clicked!")
}
```

(Edit: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371194/set-action-listener-programmatically-in-swift)?)