# Creating extra UI Buttons programmatically in Swift unintentionally? How to run code once

Tags: swift, user-interface

I'm quite new to iOS and swift, and am running into a few problems. I know there must be some best practice here, and so would like to know the best way to do it instead of hacking at it. It may be a silly question.

I have to create a set of buttons programmatically from an array, and I do it in a **ViewController.swift** under **viewDidLoad.** I load a window and it runs "setupButtons()" and runs the setupButtons creating them in a row, as well as printing a line for each button I create. It does this every time the view loads (obviously).

Is this ok?

**Should I be creating these buttons somewhere else other than ViewController I am currently in?**

Does it remove the buttons (or whole ViewController) as the ViewController is changed? (as I change ViewControllers from a menu in the app for example?)

Apologies if my questions are beginner. I have tried to find solutions outside of asking questions on stackoverflow but haven't managed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a button programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-to-create-a-button-programmatically)

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this ok?

Yes. `viewDidLoad` is called exactly once in the lifetime of a view controller instance, so it is a good place to configure / populate your view controller's view.

Comment: Thanks matt...only one question at a time too! Got it