# How to Create Counter Button using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm a newbie coder. I need to create a counter button. For example, I create an 'A' button, when I press it, the value of A is 1 and if I pressed it again, the value goes to 2. And that count is for chart purpose. Can someone help me how to create this?

Comment: value of A ? do you mean button title ?

Comment: Do you want to do it using interface builder or all in code?

Comment: there are tons of exampls for this!!! DO some research before posting the quesiton!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a button programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-to-create-a-button-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you simply.

```
        let butt=UIButton()
        butt.setTitle("A", forState: .Normal)
        butt.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
        butt.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        butt.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(butt)

    var counter=0;
    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton){

        ++counter
        print(counter)

    }
```