# How To Programatically Create A Button Action

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uikit

I'm a new developer to Xcode and I've been struggling getting a hang of it. For my application I was creating a horizontal scroll view with buttons inside of it. In viewDidLoad() I create my scrollView and 3 different buttons within it just fine but I'm not quite sure how to give the buttons an Action. I want it so that if you tap on a certain button, it will bring you to that specific view controller [Here's the code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfG4t.png)

Comment: Add code as text to your question instead of image.

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423784/6783598

Comment: I see several issues here. First, you're not setting any constraints on any of your views so your UI will not display correctly. Second, you need to add targets to your buttons so that they can respond to events (`button.addTarget(self, action: action: #selector(someObjcMethod), for: .touchUpInside)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addTarget(_:action:for:)`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let aButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    aButton.setTitle("Tap me", for: .normal)
    aButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  @objc func onTapButton() {
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create func to handle touches. Since you are doing in code you don't need to add @IBAction.

```
@objc
func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }
    print(button.tag)
}
```

Add target to button

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You can use same target for all your buttons. Add different tags to each button so you know which one was touched.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget