# How do I create/add UIView after viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rx-swift, ios-autolayout

I am trying to create buttons after getting response from a network request. How do I do this and position them after creating them, **after the view is loaded**. I am also creating my views programmatically and using AutoLayout.

**CustomView.swift**

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
// Load custom view
override func loadView() {
    view = CustomView()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create buttons after getting response
    viewModel.output.apiOutput
        .subscribe(onNext: { posts in
            for post in posts {
                // create buttons
            }
        })
        .dispose(by: disposeBag)

}
```

Comment: I recommend that you create the button and put it on the main view in `viewDidLoad` and just hide/show it at the right time. That's much easier.

Comment: The problem is I do not know how many buttons I need to create until the response comes back.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// Helper function to create a new button.
func createButton(_ title: String) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .blue
    button.setTitle(title, .normal)

    // Add the button as a subview.
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Just set the viewController's view to your custom view here.
    self.view = CustomView()

    // Create buttons after getting response
    viewModel.output.apiOutput
        .subscribe(onNext: { posts in
            for post in posts {
                // Create a button. Change "title" to the title of your post, etc.
                let button = createButton("Title")
                // Constrain your button here!
            }
        })
        .dispose(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Where it says `// Constrain your button here!` - if you want multiple buttons in a row or column, I'd recommend using a UIStackView, and adding them as ArrangedSubviews, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your buttons to an override of viewWillAppear()

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear

Or this older posting might help you out:

[How to create a button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-to-create-a-button-programmatically)

But I would try using viewWillAppear() first

Comment: I am trying to create button after the view is loaded.