# How to assign a button’s action in code using @objc mark for given function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Hi for this question I found answer on [How to create a button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030348/how-to-create-a-button-programmatically) however still facing the errors: "Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'plusOne(sender:)'" and "@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes". If you can advice.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 60, height: 60)
button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusOne), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
    
@objc func plusOne(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.count += 1 
    self.label.text = "\(self.count)"
}
```

Comment: Where does this code sit?  Is it in a viewController, or related object, or are you trying to wrie this at a global level within a playground?

Comment: @flanker git@github.com:Mairoslav/ClickCounter.git the code is in  override func viewDidLoad() {... within class ViewController: UIViewController { in ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you've nested the `@objc func plusOne(sender: UIButton!)` within `viewDidLoad` (which was why i asked the initial question about scope).  You need to move it out to a class-scope method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  // all the usual stuff...

  let button = UIButton()
  button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 60, height: 60)
  button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
  button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusOne), for: .touchUpInside)
  self.view.addSubview(button)

}

@objc func plusOne(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.count += 1 
    self.label.text = "\(self.count)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method is `plusOne(sender:)`, the argument labels make part of the name

Comment: I tried to write the function as per your suggestion action: #selector(incrementCount(sender:)) still could not work it out. git@github.com:Mairoslav/ClickCounter.git

Comment: @mairo - move your function outside the `viewDidLoad` Button handler should not be within the scope of another function.

Comment: @Nathan Day While correct in the naming of the method, you don't need to specify the labels when using in a `#selector`.  For example `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)` is valid for a method with signature `@objc private func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton)`

Comment: thank you @shawnfrank for useful help, I am careful about this now. Cheers.